# unable to import and use typescript socket.io

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, websocket, socket.io

Im attempting to use the npm typescript @types/socket.io definition.
To install, I simply:

```
npm install --save @types/socket.io
npm install --save socket.io
```

This updated my package.json to look like so:

```
...

 "devDependencies": {
    "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.8",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  }
```

In my TS file I attempt to:

```
// client.ts
// this file is compiled to js with tsc like so: tsc client.ts
import IO from 'socket.io';

 let socket = IO("http://localhost:3030");
 socket.emit("message", "HELLO!");
```

my index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />

    <script type="module" src="client.js"></script>

</head>
</html>
```

python server for hosting the html:

```
#server.py

import http.server
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import socketserver

PORT = 8080

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

Handler.extensions_map = {
    '.manifest': 'text/cache-manifest',
    '.html': 'text/html',
    '.png': 'image/png',
    '.jpg': 'image/jpg',
    '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
    '.css': 'text/css',
    '.js':  'application/x-javascript',
    '': 'application/wasm',  # Default
}

httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

which throws this in the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "socket.io". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I currently see that i have a node_modules folder in my current path along with the @types subfolder that contains the socket.io definitions. I also have the regular socket.io js folder under node_modules. Typescript compiles everything just fine with no errors.

I thought that after doing npm install @types/ , typescript would smartly use the installed package without any further tweaking.

My tsconfig.json looks like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "ES6",
        "outDir": "out",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "watch": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowJs": true,
    }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.8",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

Can anyone give me some ideas on what I am possibly doing wrong? Am I using socket.io incorrectly? Am I importing socket.io incorrectly? Did I npm install socket.io @types incorrectly? Are my typescript settings messed up?

Comment: Hi, It might be a problem with running the files. what is your dev script?

Comment: added my dev files.

Comment: Inside your `package.json` there should be a `scripts` part where you run via `npm run command` can you also add those please. How do you run your server on your terminal?

Comment: Its just a standard python http server. I run the server like:

python server.py

Comment: I also added my package.json. I do not have any 'scripts' part

Comment: So you have a `client.ts` file and you are referancing `out/client.js` file in your html. There should be a building part of your code through typescript to javascript. before you run your server can you try to compile your typescript code into javascript and then start your python server it should work

Comment: That did not work. Not sure what compiling it before starting the server would do?  Also I added a few more lines to the server so it can be aware of more media types.

Comment: Browsers can not use `.ts` files so typescript files has to convert to javascript files. please refer https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-tutorial here how to convert your files before you run your server

Comment: I understand they cannot use .ts files. I have a tsc watcher in the background converting it. I put the directions on how to compile to ts and modified my index html to make it easier for people to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured things out.

The problem was that my client server (hosting the page), needed the actual cdn or js socketio file. Also when creating client.ts, there is no need to do imports. Use the javascript functions as normal because the definition files (.d.ts - which i grabbed from node_modules) will figure out the types automatically. This will transpile to js that the client hosted html page can use with the given CDN.

The server can be run on node and this is much easier because npm install can place the modules and typescript file in node_modules with node automatically configures and knows about.

Comment: Hello, can you give more information about how you got your client.ts working? I have posted a question about an issue with my client side TS file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956705/uncaught-typeerror-while-importing-socket-io-in-client-side-typescript-file) . Thank you

Comment: hey It has been a while since I looked at this. I do not recall how I solved it lol... But based on what I wrote, it seems like the server needs the actual javascript socketio file. Basically wrote java script from the TS file.